# API for uploading synonyms via Google Search Appliance ( GSA )

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

I am using Google Search Appliance (GSA) on a project. We wanted to use query expansion to make searching more effective. Currently we are using the front-end to upload the synonym file.

Is there an API which GSA provides to automatically upload the synonyms. An API does exist for Google Custom Search, but could not find one for GSA.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a direct API for this.  The API to the administrative console can be found

http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/acapi_protocol/index.html

You could write a screenscrapper and perform a form post to achieve what you are wanting to do.